# obtain buyers name and shipping address through return url

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am experimenting with `PayPal-sandbox` for an online shop that I am endeavouring to build. As it currently stands the buyer simply selects a product, clicks the buy now button and is then sent to PayPal to complete the transaction.

After such, I have a function that makes use of the return url to store the transaction details in my orders tables.

[image]

Everything works fine but I am wondering if it is also possible to capture the buyers name and shipping address from the PayPal form using the return url.

```
function process_transaction() {



if(isset($_GET['tx'])) { // ie. if transaction sale has been completed....

$amount = $_GET['amt']; // get amount details for our db
$currency = $_GET['cc'];
$transaction = $_GET['tx']; // get transaction details and we will bump into our db
$status = $_GET['st']; // get status, ie completed
$total = 0; // default product total variables set to zero in the first instance 
$item_quantity = 0;   // default quantity variable set to zero 




$send_order = query(" INSERT INTO orders (order_amount, order_transaction, order_status, order_currency) VALUES('{$amount}','{$transaction}','{$status}','{$currency}')");



confirm($send_order); 


$last_id = last_id(); 



foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) { 


if($value > 0 ) { 


if(substr($name, 0, 8) == "product_") { 


$length = strlen($name) - 8; 

$id = substr($name, 8 , $length);




$query = query(" SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = " . escape_string($id). " " );

confirm($query);



while ($row = fetch_array($query)) {

$product_price = $row['product_price'];
$sub = $row['product_price']*$value;
$item_quantity +=$value;



$insert_report = query(" INSERT INTO reports (product_id, order_id, product_price, product_quantity) VALUES('{$id}','{$last_id}','{$product_price}','{$value}')");
confirm($insert_report); //runs the confirm helper method  




} // end of while loop


$total += $sub; 
echo $item_quantity; 


} // end of substring if statement




}




} 


session_destroy();

} else {


redirect("index.php");


} 




}
```

Comment: What does the return URL look like? Can you post an example here? Obviously without any real customer data in it please...

Comment: yes, I will do so in a minute,

Comment: @yinken added small image above of an example of return url data

Answer (score 0):

The information you are adding to your database is coming from the URL string, as you said, using PHP `$amount = $_GET['amt']`, etc. Your buyer's name and all other information would have to be parsed in the same way, if it is included in that string, for example in the form of "&customer_name=firstname_lastname".

My guess is though, that it will not be. It would be completely insecure to transmit any sensitive data in such a way.

You will have to get customer information from another source. You should be getting it anyway, since you will have to collect it in your web shop at one point.